# How do I figure which words users typically use together in search?

Tags: seo, keywords, research

Not all verbs work with all nouns. It is better to say "fix errors" than "solve errors", for example. These are called collocations.

How do I figure out what verbs a person would typically type in Google along with keywords used on my site?  How do I do keyword analysis to better target users needs?

Comment: Short answer? You do not need to do this! Using your example, fix and solve are synonyms. Search engines use ontologies for understanding language. Semantically speaking, your examples are identical. Search is not about keywords. SEs do not make search term matches. That is not how search works. It has not been for a very very long time. Understanding intent is the name of the game. Forget the keyword chase. You do not need to social engineer any SE. Just write naturally and let the 70k engineers figure it out. I assure you, they got this!

Comment: I am going to repeat myself differently. You don't need to do this. Synonyms are handled automatically using an ontology specific to synonyms. The difference between the two is moot because both are considered regardless of which query is used. The SERP order may prefer the search term used, but of course that would make sense wouldn't it? All synonyms are included for each query. Period.

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer has always been 'use Google Keyword Planner', but don't it is flawed. This video outlines why:

https://moz.com/blog/unreliable-google-adwords-keyword-volume

A general approach to keyword research is here:

https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/keyword-research

But instead of using keyword planner use something like Ahref Keyword Explorer (it isn't free):

https://ahrefs.com/keywords-explorer

A good free tool is the Keyword Shi*ter here:

http://keywordshitter.com/

You need to go through this yourself as it scrapes Google quick answer queries and can come back with a lot of rubbish. Also, it doesn't provide search volumes. I use this a lot.

The best data to use is Google Search Console data or run a small paid search campaign to test keywords as this data is proprietary and unique to your website.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Google keyword planner is likely to be the best way to determine keywords for your industry.

https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/keyword-planner/

You can compare keywords "fix errors" and "solve errors" to a business niche such as "computers" to find out which keyword phrases are most popular.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem there are several ways. You can follow these.

**1. Google Keywords Planner:** Although nowadays it's not giving organic result but you can use it as a free tools.

**2. Google Search Trends:** Through this tools you can know which word visitors are searching well with search volume. Like "fix errors" than "solve errors".

**3. Google Suggestions:** When we search at Google then Google shows us some autosuggestion with relevancy. Through these types of keywords people are searching also. And when we search with Google, it will show us “related searches” at the bottom of the page.
[image]